# How to hide methods outside the class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do something, but I don't know if it's possible
I have these classes:

```
public Class1
{
    private Class2 class2;

    public Class1
    {
        this.class2 = new Class2();
    }

    public Class2 Do()
    {
        return class2.Build();
    }
}

internal Class2
{
    public internal Class2 Build()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void Fill()
    {
    }
}

var class1 = new Class1();
class1.Do().Fill();
```

I want it when the user types class1.Do (). only the Fill () method is accessible. How can I do this?

The goal would be to prevent class1.Do().Build();

Comment: So the goal would be to prevent `class1.Do().Build();`?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb YES! the goal!

Comment: What you want is a "Fluent Interface."  Study that topic.

Comment: The best would be to create an interface exposing "Fill()" and implement it in the Class2.
The return type of the "Do()" method in the Class1 should be that interface.

Comment: Is this your actual code? You're missing the `class` keyword multiple times, and you can't have `public internal` modifiers together like that. Also missing parentheses for the `Class1` constructor. Also an accessibility issue with `Do()`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few errors in the code posted as mentioned in a comment. For the sake of an example answer, I made all of the troublesome places public. So while this will compile, take it with a grain of salt and adjust your accessibility modifiers appropriately.

Firstly, I created a new interface to only expose Fill, and not Build:

```
public interface IClass2Helper
{
    void Fill();
}
```

I made a couple of small changes to `Class1` and `Class2` so that they become compilable, to implement the interface in `Class2` and return the interface in the `Do()` method in `Class1`:

```
public class Class1
{
    private Class2 class2;

    public Class1()
    {
        this.class2 = new Class2();
    }

    public IClass2Helper Do()
    {
        return class2.Build();
    }
}

public class Class2 : IClass2Helper
{
    public Class2 Build()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void Fill() { }
}
```

And added a simple test class/method to verify:

```
class TestProgram
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var class1 = new Class1();
        class1.Do().Fill(); //This line is OK

        //The below line will have an error since the interface doesn't expose a Build method
        class1.Do().Build(); 
    }
}
```

A fiddle to the code:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/5EPPfO